# Script that put some data in a .csv file created the file , but it's blank

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Well basically , the code that I created has to do 3 things :
1 - Read the temperature from a DS18B20 sensor
2 - Write the temperature with the time when it was verified in a .csv file
3 - Draw a graphic with the data from the .csv file
This is the code :

```
import os
import glob
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c
while True:
    print(read_temp())  
    time.sleep(1)
with open("/home/pi/cpu_temp.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:
        temp = temp_c
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),str(temp)))
        sleep(5)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
x = []
y = []
y.append(temp)
x.append(time())
plt.clf()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.draw
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem ? I would've fix it myself without asking this question, but I actually don't know what is wrong , the code runs just fine , no errors.

Comment: `while True:` means it'll be an infinite loop. I'm not sure how can this run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your write to file code block:

```
with open("/home/pi/cpu_temp.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:
        temp = temp_c
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),str(temp)))
        sleep(5)
```

is never executed, because an infinite loop is executed before it:

```
while True:
    print(read_temp())  
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you , I actually combined 2 codes together to made this , I tought i removed it but it seems like i didn't.